# C# SQL Sum of a column (salary) where the ID = 2

Tags: c#, sql

I've managed to sum the whole column, but that's not what I wanted. I need the sum of column(salary) values by a button click where the Employee ID is the same as in a TextBox(txtBox1)

My code:

```
label4.Text = "0";
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
      label4.Text = Convert.ToString(double.Parse(label4.Text) 
           + double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()));
}
```

Now I need something like that `"select sum(salray) from employee where Employee_ID='" + txtBox1 "')"`;

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want the sum of a column in your database or in your DataGridView?

Comment: This code is not enough to answer your question.

Comment: Don't see any sql here

Comment: Don't concatenate SQL like that based purely on user input. Use parameterized queries!

Comment: Aside: summing in a text label, like you do here, is terribly inefficient and also brittle. It's much better to do the sum in a local variable with the type of the cell value's native format (int, double, or whatever) and then assign the result to the label once done looping.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is pretty simple and there is no sql needed.
I assume that you have multiple employees inside your Datagrid and a structure like this:

| EmployeID | Year | Salery |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018 | 100000 |
| 2 | 2018 | 100000 |
| 3 | 2018 | 100000 |
| 1 | 2019 | 100000 |
| 1 | 2020 | 100000 |

The only thing you have to do is to check the Id value of each row.
If it matches the given Id, Sum up the saleries. If not continue

```
label4.Text = "0";
string employeId = filter.Text;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
      if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(employeId))
      {
           if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == employeId)
           {
                label4.Text = Convert.ToString(double.Parse(label4.Text) 
                + double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()));
           }

      }
}
```